# App rotation works in iOS7 but not iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, uikit

I'm having problems getting my app to rotate between portrait and landscape orientations in iOS8. It works fine in iOS7. In my main view controller I have the following.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;     // for iOS7 compatibility
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

I can confirm (through debugging) that the latter two are called at startup under iOS8, but not on screen rotation.

I am using auto-layout and have zero errors and warnings in IB. (Also none in the debugger on start up).

The Info.plist file has all 4 orientations for 'UISupportedInterfaceOrientations' and 'UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad'.

It's a little unusual because in the simulator (8.1) the app always launches in portrait mode, regardless of orientation. However on a device (8.0) the app always launches in the current orientation. Neither will allow in-app rotation however.

I have scoured the internet and Apple's documentation. Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the issue. I had been calling 'beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications' from within the application delegate's 'initialize' method:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    // ...
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

This has worked fine since early iOS days, and the call doesn't seem to be deprecated, but for some reason it no longer works in iOS8 -- at least not at this early stage. Easily worked around. Thanks to all who considered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Click on your project first.
2) Then click on General tab.under deployment info you'll find Device orientations.
3) Check all the four option.

May be this will help you.
Do inform me if it wont work.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks but they're already checked. That's what I meant by UISupportedInterfaceOrientations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your appdelegate.

```
 -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
else  /* iphone */
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had missed that particular call, but it hasn't made any difference.